# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: Unable to enlist in a distributed transaction

Tags: oracle, transactions, biztalk, msdtc, biztalk-2016

We are installing a new BizTalk Server 2016 environment and we are migrating an old application with **WCF-Custom + OracleDBBinding** Send Port, with **useAmbientTransaction** = true.

In the old environment (BizTalk 2009) is working fine and in the new environment we are testing with the same destination Oracle and PL.

In the new environment, we are receiving this error:

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: Unable to enlist in a distributed transaction

If we set **useAmbientTransaction** = false, works fine.

Oracle MTS Service is running.

Any help?

**Additional Edit**

I have activated Oracle MTS traces and the error is:

> OCI_ERROR - 2048
>
> ORA-02048: attempt to begin distributed transaction without logging on

**Additional Edit (2)**

We uninstall the Oracle Client 12c and install Oracle Client 11g as the previous environment. Now works.

Comment: Have you verified that all the DTC settings in Windows are exactly the same as the old enviro?

Comment: Yes, are the same settings :-(

Comment: Are you using the host instance credentials to log in to the Oracle Database?  Is this user different between BizTalk 2009 & BizTalk 2016?  If yes, has the BizTalk 2016 user have the correct rights on the Oracle Database?

Comment: The user credentials to log in to the Oracle Database are set in Credentials tab on the Send Port an are the same that in BizTalk 2009. Also Host Instance user is the same in BizTalk 2009.